# New query taking over 60% of running time

Tags: postgresql, optimization, postgresql-9.4, explain

As part of a daily automated reporting system, we run a series of queries to check different operating parameters from our customers' assets tables.

Last Tuesday I added a new check that works, but triggered a few performance alarms that led me to analyze what might be wrong and I ended up realizing that the new check actually increased the overall checks time about 160%.

Drilling down this new check I narrowed it to actual DB query that is affecting the whole process:

```
select case COALESCE(max(driverid),-1) when 0 then false when -1 then null else true end 
from reports.avl_historico_354676052451142 
where DATE_PART('day', now() - fecha ) < 5;
```

And when doing an `explain analyze verbose`, I get:

```
Aggregate  (cost=75004.56..75004.58 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=544.460..544.461 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: CASE COALESCE(max(driverid), (-1)) WHEN 0 THEN false WHEN (-1) THEN NULL::boolean ELSE true END
  ->  Seq Scan on reports.avl_historico_354676052451142  (cost=0.00..73782.38 rows=488873 width=4) (actual time=535.565..541.467 rows=9661 loops=1)
        Output: fecha, latitud, longitud, altitud, velocidad, cog, nsat, tipo, utc_hora, fix_fecha, imei, registro, input1, input2, input3, input4, hdop, adc, ignicion, adc2, power, driverid, ibutton2, ibutton3, ibutton4, trailerid, adc3, adc4, horometro, odometro, panico, bateria, bateriaint
        Filter: (date_part('day'::text, (now() - avl_historico_354676052451142.fecha)) < 5::double precision)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1457143
Planning time: 0.078 ms
Execution time: 544.582 ms
```

So I'm guessing that this query might need some kind of help / improvement, but I'm completely clueless about it. So I'm asking: what improvements would you recommend for this scenario? Indexes? Query rephrasing? Others? What else should I provide for deeper understanding of the model?

Please consider that the sample table in the query has a large number in its name, which stands for a deviceId and we have around 30k tables of those which are queried regularly...it's some kind of a table partitioning model.

**Update!**

New results from the indexing suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name :

```
Aggregate  (cost=5478.72..5478.74 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=8.302..8.302 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: CASE COALESCE(max(driverid), (-1)) WHEN 0 THEN false WHEN (-1) THEN NULL::boolean ELSE true END
  ->  Index Scan using reports_avl_historico_354676052451142_index_fecha on reports.avl_historico_354676052451142  (cost=0.43..5473.68 rows=2017 width=4) (actual time=0.026..4.644 rows=12249 loops=1)
        Output: fecha, latitud, longitud, altitud, velocidad, cog, nsat, tipo, utc_hora, fix_fecha, imei, registro, input1, input2, input3, input4, hdop, adc, ignicion, adc2, power, driverid, ibutton2, ibutton3, ibutton4, trailerid, adc3, adc4, horometro, odometro, panico, bateria, bateriaint
        Index Cond: (avl_historico_354676052451142.fecha > (('now'::cstring)::date - 5))
Planning time: 0.181 ms
Execution time: 8.332 ms
```

I'll time the overall execution and keep you posted.

Comment: Does `analyze avl_historico_354676052451142` change anything? What are the indexes defined on  that table? If you have an index on `fecha` you could rewrite the condition to: `where fecha > current_date - 5` so that Postgres can make use of that index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess using `analyze` won't be an option as it would need to be run before the query execution so the overall time wouldn't decrease as the tables hold 1 year of historical information with 1467004 for that specific table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name regarding indexes it does have one based on fecha, as follow: `CREATE INDEX reports_avl_historico_354676052451142_index_fecha ON reports.avl_historico_354676052451142 USING btree (fecha)` I'll try your suggestion, but how can I compare the results using `explain` so if it improves?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your suggestion works amazing: it went from 60% down to 7% now. I'll try and apply that suggestion to other queries too that I have around. Great to learn from the gurus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `where DATE_PART('day', now() - fecha ) < 5` can not make use of an index on the column `fecha`.

Rewrite the expression so that it can use an index:

```
where fecha > current_date - 5
```

Comment: Done, and performed great!